# Canonical URL compare in Python?

Tags: python, fuzzy-comparison

Are there any tools to do a URL compare in Python?

For example, if I have `http://google.com` and `google.com/` I'd like to know that they are likely to be the same site.

If I were to construct a rule manually, I might Uppercase it, then strip off the `http://` portion, and drop anything after the last alpha-numeric character.. But I can see failures of this, as I'm sure you can as well.

Is there a library that does this? How would you do it?

Comment: It won't let you post two _links_ without X reputation, but you can include as many URLs as you want if you put them in backquotes so that the parser doesn't convert them to links. I edited your question to show what I think you meant, but if I got it wrong please do edit it again to correct me.

Comment: Oh, and another thing: what exactly do you mean by "fuzzy" comparison? It's easy to tell that `http://google.com` and `google.com/` are the same thing because they have the exact same canonical form, but that's not fuzzy comparison. A real fuzzy comparison would identify URLs that are similar, but not identical, even after you convert them to a standard form.

Comment: Thanks, still very new to SO. I've changed the title.

Comment: http://intertwingly.net/stories/2004/08/04/urlnorm.py seems like it might be a good starting place.

Answer (score 3):

There is [quite a bit to creating a canonical url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_normalization) apparently.
The [url-normalize](https://pypi.org/project/url-normalize/) library is best that I have tested.

Depending on the source of your urls you may wish to clean them of other standard parameters such as [UTM codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters). [w3lib.url.url_query_cleaner](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.url_query_cleaner) is useful for this.

Combining this with [Ned Batchelder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3285436/3969685) could look something like:

**Code:**

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner
from url_normalize import url_normalize

urls = ['google.com',
'google.com/',
'http://google.com/',
'http://google.com',
'http://google.com?',
'http://google.com/?',
'http://google.com//',
'http://google.com?utm_source=Google']


def canonical_url(u):
    u = url_normalize(u)
    u = url_query_cleaner(u,parameterlist = ['utm_source','utm_medium','utm_campaign','utm_term','utm_content'],remove=True)

    if u.startswith("http://"):
        u = u[7:]
    if u.startswith("https://"):
        u = u[8:]
    if u.startswith("www."):
        u = u[4:]
    if u.endswith("/"):
        u = u[:-1]
    return u

list(map(canonical_url,urls))
```

**Result:**

```
['google.com',
 'google.com',
 'google.com',
 'google.com',
 'google.com',
 'google.com',
 'google.com',
 'google.com']
```

Answer (score 2):

This off the top of my head:

```
def canonical_url(u):
    u = u.lower()
    if u.startswith("http://"):
        u = u[7:]
    if u.startswith("www."):
        u = u[4:]
    if u.endswith("/"):
        u = u[:-1]
    return u

def same_urls(u1, u2):
    return canonical_url(u1) == canonical_url(u2)
```

Obviously, there's lots of room for more fiddling with this.  Regexes might be better than startswith and endswith, but you get the idea.

Comment: That's similar to what I'd build if I was going to do it manually. I was hoping there was a lib that already does this. It seems like it should be a solved-problem.

Comment: @Colin: This is one of those things where doing it yourself is usually easy enough, and more likely to get you what you really want. The thing is that there is no strictly defined 'canonical form' of a URL, so everyone who wants it is thinking something slightly different.

Comment: I agree with Nicholas: this isn't well-defined enough to have gotten a standard definition.  You'll be best served by writing it yourself.

Comment: lower-casing the whole URL strikes me as a bad idea-- case does matter in URL's (aside from the host and domain)

Answer (score 1):

You could look up the names using dns and see if they point to the same ip.  Some minor string processing may be required to remove confusing chars.

```
from socket import gethostbyname_ex

urls = ['http://google.com','google.com/','www.google.com/','news.google.com']

data = []
for orginalName in urls:
    print 'url:',orginalName
    name = orginalName.strip()
    name = name.replace( 'http://','')
    name = name.replace( 'http:','')
    if name.find('/') > 0:
        name = name[:name.find('/')]
    if name.find('\\') > 0:
        name = name[:name.find('\\')]
    print 'dns lookup:', name
    if name:
        try:
            result = gethostbyname_ex(name)
        except:
            continue # Unable to resolve
        for ip in result[2]:
            print 'ip:', ip
            data.append( (ip, orginalName) )

print data
```

result:

```
url: http://google.com
dns lookup: google.com
ip: 66.102.11.104
url: google.com/
dns lookup: google.com
ip: 66.102.11.104
url: www.google.com/
dns lookup: www.google.com
ip: 66.102.11.104
url: news.google.com
dns lookup: news.google.com
ip: 66.102.11.104
[('66.102.11.104', 'http://google.com'), ('66.102.11.104', 'google.com/'), ('66.102.11.104', 'www.google.com/'), ('66.102.11.104', 'news.google.com')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The original answer from @Antony is good, but I didn't like that it uses two libraries (`w3lib` and `url-normalize`), while `url-normalize` hasn't been maintained since Jan 2022.

`w3lib` is part of `scrapy` and thus more maintained/stable, and in its doc I found the following handy dandy function:

> `w3lib.url.canonicalize_url(url: Union[str, bytes, ParseResult], keep_blank_values: bool = True, keep_fragments: bool = False, encoding: Optional[str] = None) -> str`
>
> Canonicalize the given url by applying the following procedures:
>
> - make the URL safe
> - sort query arguments, first by key, then by value
> - normalize all spaces (in query arguments) ‘+’ (plus symbol)
> - normalize percent encodings case (%2f -> %2F)
> - remove query arguments with blank values (unless keep_blank_values is True)
> - remove fragments (unless keep_fragments is True)
>
> The url passed can be bytes or unicode, while the url returned is always a native str (bytes in Python 2, unicode in Python 3).

#### Usage

```py
import w3lib.url

# sorting query arguments
w3lib.url.canonicalize_url('http://www.example.com/do?c=3&b=5&b=2&a=50')
'http://www.example.com/do?a=50&b=2&b=5&c=3'

# UTF-8 conversion + percent-encoding of non-ASCII characters
w3lib.url.canonicalize_url('http://www.example.com/r\u00e9sum\u00e9')
'http://www.example.com/r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9'
```

#### [Source](https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.canonicalize_url)

I really value a stable solution, as opposed to one that relies on multiple odd libraries, since my use-case is to generate unique ids by hashing the canonicalised URL.

Btw, I think this function could be combined with

```py
def canonical_url(u):
    u = u.lower()
    if u.startswith("http://"):
        u = u[7:]
    if u.startswith("www."):
        u = u[4:]
    if u.endswith("/"):
        u = u[:-1]
    return u
```

from @Ned Batchelder 's answer

Answer (score -1):

It's not 'fuzzy', it just find the 'distance' between two strings:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/

I would remove all portions which are semantically meaningful to URL parsing (protocol, slashes, etc.), normalize to lowercase, then perform a levenstein distance, then from there decide how many difference is an acceptable threshold.

Just an idea.